how to configure installation location pyproject.toml (python PEP517)
This is a python package installation question. If I have a project named foo, how can I configure create a setuptools-based project using pyproject.toml (PEP517) to install to a subdirectory (AKA namespace?) in site-packages/ named foo2?
Two ways I can think of:

configure pyproject.toml with the right knobs that I currently don't know
allow the distribution package (AKA wheel?) to install to the default subdirectory (e.g, foo/) under site-packages, but tell pip to override that location when the package is installed.

I am interested in details about both options. Or just pointers to the documentation that describes these things - I have not found the documentation for pyproject.toml configuration that would provide a way to specify installation location.
I would like to minimize dependencies - basic python standard library preferred along with minimal additional dependencies, if any.
I realize there is a selection of build backends to choose from, so other build backends than just 'setuptools' are interesting (flit-core, hatchling, poetry, etc.). I would like to understand how to use setuptools as the backend at a minimum.
For now, thinking about a simple (e.g., pure python) project is fine. I'll move on to "fancier" needs (e.g., including C or Rust extensions) later.

Neither is possible so there are no docs. If your top-level importable package (directory with __init__.py) is foo it will be packed as foo and install as foo. No renaming, the end of the story.

The "distribution package" and the top-level "import package" can have different names. It is not the convention, it is frowned upon, but it is possible. -- If in your pyproject.toml you set the distribution package name with project.name = "foo", but you have your top-level import package foo2/__init__.py, then it will break setuptools' "automatic package discovery".

pyproject.toml

build system requirements and information, which are used by pip to build the package.

So its responsible for what is inside the package. A package installer like pip provides means to set a target directory other than the default
pip --target

Install packages into <dir>. By default this will not replace existing files/folders in <dir>.
Use --upgrade to replace existing packages in <dir> with new versions.
(environment variable: PIP_TARGET)


Structure your package:
|- src
|   |- foo2
|       |- foo
|           |- __init__.py
|- pyproject.toml

Then in pyproject.toml use:
[project]
name          = "foo"
license       = {text = "MIT License"}
version       = "0.0.1"

[build-system]
requires      = [ "setuptools" ]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

When you install the package, it will be installed to site_packages/foo2/foo.

You can find out more in the Packaging Namespace Packages documentation.

Thanks.  How did you figure this out?  Docs somewhere? Code dive?

@Juan I've used it before to create packages with different optional extras so, this time, I just looked at some old code. But, since you've asked for docs, I've added a link to the Namespace Packages documentation which gives more information and refers to PEP420.

Note that it also means that foo2 is the "top-level import package" (and also a "namespace import package"). So the imports have to start with foo2, for example: from foo2 import foo or import foo2.foo.

True.  I would prefer a knob I could set in pyproject.toml that just changed the top level name.  (like 'destination = foo2' or similar somewhere in the pyproject.toml file - or setup.cfg / setup.py)
